# How do I execute functions via sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv, sys

I'm very new to coding (started 2 days ago) and for practice a friend gave me the task of writing a program that provides either the nth Fibonacci number or the sequence up to the nth point. I successfully completed that task using input() and directly asking the user for an n, now he extended the task and asked me to try getting the same results using sys.argv

After extensive use of google I figured out how to print all the given arguments and count them, but I cannot figure out any way of using those arguments in a function. Unfortunately I also can't seem to find the right keywords for google, leaving me a little stuck in no mans land.

Here's my most recent attempt:

```
import sys
from math import sqrt
print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
Fibonacci = sys.argv[0]
value = sys.argv[1]
sequence = sys.argv[2]
def fib(value): int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**value-(((1-sqrt(5))/2)**value)))

print("The {}. value is".format(value), fib(value))

input("Close")
```

(Small detail, albeit unimportant: I translated the strings from German to English, which is also why it says "{}. value" rather than "{}st/nd/rd/th", the differentiation between those cases is a problem for a later date.)

Now I expect to be miles off target here, but using some of the expressions that worked for my input() based code is pretty much the last idea I have right now. Can anyone give me a pointer on how I can proceed here? Even a hint on what I should google would help, but as of now I'm completely out of ideas.

EDIT: I don't know if this is what you're supposed to do, but I've solved my problem and I thought I might as well post my code in case someone else stumbles upon this thread with a similar question. Here's my solution.

```
import sys
from math import sqrt
Fibonacci = sys.argv[0]
Entscheidung = (sys.argv[1])
n = int(sys.argv[2])
sequence = []

if Entscheidung == "Stelle":
    def fib(n): return int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**n-((1-sqrt(5))/2)**n))
    print("Die {}. Stelle beträgt:{}".format(n, fib(n)))
elif Entscheidung == "Folge":
    def fib(n): return int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**n-((1-sqrt(5))/2)**n))
    for i in range(n): 
        sequence.append(fib(i + 1))
    print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, sequence)))    


input("Schließen")
```

Note that I'm still an absolute beginner and this solution might be inefficient, badly written, confusingly formatted, I wouldn't know. All I can guarantee is that it does the job.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list of *strings*. How did you handle the string returned from `input()`?

Comment: `n = int(input("Wie viele Stellen der Folge willst du?"))` was how I converted the input into an integer, I tried to do that by saying `def fib((int)value): int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**value-(((1-sqrt(5))/2)**value)))` but that did not work. can I convert it into an int in the line `value = sys.argv[1]`? I will try that momentarily and report back

Comment: Alright, I edited the 6th line to read `value = int(sys.argv[1])` and that did indeed help, the line `def fib(value): int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**value-(((1-sqrt(5))/2)**value)))` now shows "value" to be an integer, but trying to execute the program it still closes immediately, so something must definitely be wrong still. Thank you though, I really appreciate how you pointed me towards a specific part of my own code rather than outright telling me!

Comment: Alright after taking a break I indeed realized that a lot of the code from my other attempt was still applicable here and I managed to solve it! Thanks again for the help

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. You are more than welcome to post your own solution as an answer, and even accept it. Pleae do accept one of the answers here; that's how we can see that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, `n = int(sys.argv[2])` was the charm.

Now that you're an expert at cracking `sys.argv`, you might want to `$ pip install click` and let that package do some of the parsing for you: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Conditionally executing `def` is an option, I suppose, but a bit odd.
Pasting the same definition into both `if` branches is not helpful.
Just `def` it once, up top.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactoring of your code with the following changes:

- Don't define the same function twice. Instead, define two separate functions, and decide which one to call depending on the desired semantics.
- Don't capitalize variables. Capitalized names are conventionally reserved for class names in Python.
- Remove the final `input`. Surely your friend wanted you to make a program which can be properly reused; requiring user interaction ruins that.
- Don't use `sys.argv[0]` for anything. If it's not used, there's no need to capture it (and if you should need it later, it's still there).
- Wrap the entry point in `if __name__`... so that this piece of code can be `import`ed into another program without side effects.

```
from math import sqrt

def fib_nth(n):
    return int(1/sqrt(5)*(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**n-((1-sqrt(5))/2)**n))

def fib_seq(n):
    sequence = []
    for i in range(n): 
        sequence.append(fib_nth(i + 1))
    return sequence

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    entscheidung = sys.argv[1]
    n = int(sys.argv[2])

    if entscheidung == "Stelle":
        print("Die {}. Stelle beträgt:{}".format(n, fib_nth(n)))
    elif entscheidung == "Folge":
        print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, fib_seq(n))))
```